# Replacing address details in colon delimited string

Tags: strings, regex, csv

I'm sanitising personal data in a large database with a series of Regular Expressions. In many cases the sensitive data is in a colon-delimited field within a CSV file.

**Here is a sample:**

```
(142406, 202, '45759:2940:2016-04-12-21-24-08:300:2016-06-21:2016-04-11:1:Windows/Doors:', 2761, 4041931, 0, '1460492649'),
(142404, 203, '43833:1:1:1:1:4:1:1:2016-03-24', 1310, 4041377, 0, '1460491641'),
(142405, 204, '45759:Mr.:Bob:Thingy:123 Lovely Avenue:Anice Town:Acounty:TT1 1TT:01234123123:bob@example.com:2016-04-12-21-24-08', 2761, 4041931, 0, '1460492649'),
(142391, 203, '45462:1:1:1:1:5:0:1:2016-04-06', 1441, 4042573, 0, '1460477197'),
(142392, 204, '45755:Mrs.:Sandra:Wotsits:456 Pleasant Street:Agreat City:Anothercounty:TT2 2TT:01234456456:sandra@example.com:2016-04-12-17-08-13', 2869, 4030970, 0, '1460477293'),
```

**This is what I need to, and do, end up with:**

```
(142406, 202, '45759:2940:2016-04-12-21-24-08:300:2016-06-21:2016-04-11:1:Windows/Doors:', 2761, 4041931, 0, '1460492649'),
(142404, 203, '43833:1:1:1:1:4:1:1:2016-03-24', 1310, 4041377, 0, '1460491641'),
(142405, 204, '45759:Mr.:Dennis:Chalkley:123 Street:Atown:Acounty:TE5 5TT:01234123456:name@example.com:2016-04-12-21-24-08', 2761, 4041931, 0, '1460492649'),
(142391, 203, '45462:1:1:1:1:5:0:1:2016-04-06', 1441, 4042573, 0, '1460477197'),
(142392, 204, '45755:Mr.:Steven P:Kirk:123 Street:Atown:Acounty:TE5 5TT:01234123456:name@example.com:2016-04-12-17-08-13', 2869, 4030970, 0, '1460477293'),
```

Note that the only things being replaced are the address details and the email address, and these only appear in lines with '204' in the second column. All other data needs to remain as is.

I'm using these to achieve the above result:

**Search for:**

```
204, '([0-9]{5}):(.*?):(.*?):(.*?):(.*):(.*)',
```

**Replace with:**

```
204, '\1:\2:\3:\4:123 Street:Atown:Acounty:TE5 5TT:01234123456:name@example.com:\6',
```

I'm PRETTY sure my 'Search' expression can be improved a lot. Please help.

**EDIT:** Further info as requested in comments

I'm using a text editor to run the regexp (TextWrangler, Atom), and the 'Search' and 'Replace' examples I've included are what I'm entering in the relevant Find/Replace boxes.

The source of this data is a MySQL dump, and these lines are a sampling from some INPUT statements.

Eventually I plan to use this search and replacement expression in a PHP script or Stored Procedure, and will cross that bridge when I come to it.

Comment: Good attempt, but I still have no clue what you're doing. Is this what you enter always, or just an example? What are you trying to accomplish when you try to explain it in just 2 sentences?

Comment: @Mast which bit's don't you understand? Do you think I should just rewrite it? I'm removing sensitive address data from a CSV file with a RegExp. At the moment I'm doing it with a text editor but will be scripting it when I get the expression right. Well.. it works now but I'm trying to get it neater/faster before I do. I might have miss-understood what this SE site was for. I'm saying "I'm doing this, it works, but how do I make it better". Essentially I'm trying to get better at writing Regex.

Comment: I got a better idea: implement it in the script and come back to talk about it. We have no problem reviewing that. How does that sound to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is way beyond borderline abusive of regex. You may not be aware, but there are ways to parse CSV data without complicated string expressions. [Here is a PHP reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

---

[See this demo](http://regexr.com/3d77d):

[image: regex]

As you can clearly see, the moment you stop taking into account the second field `204` for filtering, your regex matches **everything**. This can be problematic in a few ways:

1. Can you guarantee that all `204` lines will only contain address credentials? Database rows sometimes contain unexpected data due to misuse of the database fields. This is especially true of user-input fields from applications that rely on the database.
2. Can you guarantee that all lines that are *not* `204` will never contain any data that you want to replace? See (1) above.

If you are unsure about either of the above, you might want to consider an alternative solution using your preferred language to give you more control over how parse the data. Your reliance on this `204` field could corrupt your data set if you are not careful. Regular expressions are powerful, but sometimes you need a scalpel and not a hammer.

---

So, let's look at the regex code itself. If you are going to be using PHP, I would recommend first looking into [extended/verbose regex mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155048/verbose-regular-expressions-in-php). This will allow you to document the expression in your code, so that the maintainer of it (which includes you 6 months in the future) will know what it is doing.

It could look something like this:

```
$LINE_204_PATTERN = 
    '/(?x) #enable verbose regex mode
        (
            [0-9]       # any numeric char
            {5}         # match 5 times
        )   # = exactly 5 numeric chars
        :           # 1 colon
        (.*?)       # lazy 0 or more of any char except line breaks
        :           # 1 colon
        (.*?)       # lazy 0 or more of any char except line breaks
        :           # 1 colon
        (.*?)       # lazy 0 or more of any char except line breaks
        :           # 1 colon
        (.*)        # 0 or more of any char except line breaks
        :           # 1 colon
        (.*)        # 0 or more of any char except line breaks
    /';
```

When you use `([0-9]{5})` you make the assumption that all IDs are *exactly* 5 numeric characters long. With that potentially being an auto-increment column in the database, chances are that some will have fewer than 5, and some will have more than 5; your expressions would not match either of those. You may consider using `([0-9]+)` instead, which will match 1 or more numeric character. If some of those fields could be null/empty, use `*` instead of `+` to match 0 or more.

The other matching groups are really just "match anything, even nothing" groups and there's only so much about them that could be improved, unless you inspect your data set very closely to look for patterns or tendencies.